# Dropdwon menu behind youtube video, why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, cross-browser, z-index

My youtube video overlaps my nav-menu in internet explorer 7,8 & 9. Ive tried to put high z-index, positioned all parent element to dropdown to relative, put  or  to the youtube object. Anyone with a fix? I'm about to launch this site in a few hours...

Link: http://nordicinvasion.minex.se/

Thanks!

Edit:
Solved it by my own. I hade to put the wmode transparent tag in embed like this:

instead of in a param in order for it to work properly.

Its now fixed.

Thanks for the quick answers anyway!

Comment: Try firebug to see what css is doing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your embed tag.

Try this:

```
<embed height="292" width="572" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/a9PMfUGEj24?controls=1&amp;hd=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;version=3&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=0" />
```

Don't forget to close the embed tag

Answer (score 0):

This should work (their demo worked in IE8 anyway):

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

http://slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/